How to implement filtering of columns with multiple labels in C# WPF .NET 8 DataGrid, combined with other filtering conditions
I am implementing filtering using an open-source library called DataGridExtensions.
I would like to implement filtering for columns with multiple labels, combined with other filtering conditions from DataGridExtensions' MultipleChoiceFilter as shown below.
How should I implement this in the view model or elsewhere?
If it is difficult with DataGridExtensions, I am also considering other open-source solutions or a custom implementation.
Filtering for columns with multiple labels:

The Clubs column contains multiple values, and I want to extract cells that include all of the selected values.




MainWindow.xaml:
<Window x:Class="TestDataGridFilterSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDataGridFilterSample"
        xmlns:dgx="urn:tom-englert.de/DataGridExtensions"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MultipleChoiceFilter">
            <dgx:MultipleChoiceFilter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- DataGrid -->
        <DataGrid x:Name="StudentDataGrid"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredStudents}"
                  dgx:DataGridFilter.IsAutoFilterEnabled="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grade" Binding="{Binding Grade}" dgx:DataGridFilterColumn.Template="{StaticResource MultipleChoiceFilter}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class" Binding="{Binding Class}" dgx:DataGridFilterColumn.Template="{StaticResource MultipleChoiceFilter}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Clubs" Binding="{Binding ClubsDisplay}" dgx:DataGridFilterColumn.Template="{StaticResource MultipleChoiceFilter}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

ViewModel/MainWindowViewModel.cs:
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using TestDataGridFilterSample.Models;

namespace TestDataGridFilterSample.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _filteredStudents;

        public ObservableCollection<Student> FilteredStudents
        {
            get => _filteredStudents;
            set => SetProperty(ref _filteredStudents, value);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Grades { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Classes { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Clubs { get; private set; }

        private List<Student> _allStudents;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            _allStudents = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student { Grade = "1", Class = "1", Clubs = new List<string> { "Sports Club", "Science Club" } },
                new Student { Grade = "2", Class = "2", Clubs = new List<string> { "Technic Club" } },
                new Student { Grade = "3", Class = "3", Clubs = new List<string> { "Sports Club" } },
                new Student { Grade = "1", Class = "3", Clubs = new List<string> { "Science Club", "Technic Club" } },
            };

            foreach (var student in _allStudents)
            {
                student.ClubsDisplay = string.Join(", ", student.Clubs);
            }

            FilteredStudents = new ObservableCollection<Student>(_allStudents);
        }
    }
}

Models/Students.cs:
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestDataGridFilterSample.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Grade { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
        public List<string> Clubs { get; set; }
        public string ClubsDisplay { get; set; }
    }
}


LINQ InteresectBy set operation.
